# When context.getSystemService is needed to create a LayoutInflater

Tags: android

Why sometimes *LayoutInflater* need to be created through *Context.getSystemService*, but sometimes it is not?

Comment: it always needs `Context.getSystemService` as there is no public constructor to create it as `new LayoutInflater(...)`